# Wrapping COM/DCOM DLL with JNI

Tags: java, c++, dll, java-native-interface, dcom

I searched for almost 2 hours for any example with complete code, but could not find anything that works. The issue is this: I have a C++ COM DLL that can comunicate with old MSJava, and I need to replace the MSJava with Sun/Oracle Java. Since the MSJava does not use JNI, the DLL is not JNI prepared. I plan to make another C++ DLL that implements JNI and from this call the old DLL. It's doable? Any advices? Examples? Thanks everyone. (If this is a duplicate please send me the link from the article)

Comment: Yes, this is fairly standard practice. Probably the most annoying bit to watch out for is multithreading, synchronization, and avoiding cross-thread JNI usage.

Comment: you dont need a seperate dll for using jni. You can implement jni wrapper functions in same dll.

Comment: thanks @Botje. But I don't have a clue on how to deal with the issues you pointed out. Any link to documentation?

Comment: thanks @idris - But at the moment whe can not recompile the sources to get a new dll.